# Replacing nth bytes with another byte in unsigned integer

Tags: c

I want to replace the byte of a with b.

```
unsigned int a = 0x12dc4430;
unsigned char b = 0xcb;
```

How can I replace the 1st and 3rd byte of a with b?

Like this:
for 1st significant byte

```
12dc33cb
```

and for 3rd significant byte

```
12cb4430
```

Answer (score 3):

Wasn't sure what you meant by "1st and 3rd byte", but assuming you meant the most significant byte and the third most significant one:

```
unsigned int a = 0x12dc4430;
unsigned char b = 0xcb;
a = (a & 0x00ff00ff) | (b << 8) | (b << 24);
printf("%x\n", a);
```

Prints cbdccb30